# Scala spark is better than pyspark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was translating pyspark to Scala spark thinking Scala spark would work well.
But Scala spark is taking more time than pyspark.
Can anyone please find issues with these two queries when its being executed in Scala spark.

> Query1 :  sqlContext.sql(SELECT           a.pair,             a.bi_count,
>             a.uni_count,            unigram_table.uni_count as uni_count_2, 
>             (log(a.bi_count) -log(a.uni_count) - log(unigram_table.uni_count))
>   as score      FROM    (               SELECT * FROM bigram_table JOIN unigram_table
>   ON bigram_table.parent = unigram_table.token              ) as a          JOIN
>   unigram_table ON a.child = unigram_table.token                WHERE a.bi_count >
>   4000      ORDER BY score DESC         limit 400000 )

Execution time in pyspark - 3 min

Execution time in Scala spark - 3 min

> Query2:  sqlContext.sql( SELECT
>             pair,           tri_count,          (log(tri_count) - log(count1) -log(count2)
>   -log(unigram_table.uni_count)) as score       FROM(           SELECT          pair,               tri_count,              count1,             child1,             child2,             unigram_table.uni_count
>   as count2         FROM (                  SELECT
>         pair,               child1,             child2,             tri_count,              unigram_table.uni_count
>   as count1                 FROM trigram_table JOIN unigram_table ON
>   trigram_table.parent = unigram_table.token    ) as a              JOIN
>   unigram_table ON a.child1 = unigram_table.token                   ) as b      JOIN
>   unigram_table ON b.child2 = unigram_table.token                   WHERE tri_count >
>   3000      ORDER BY score DES)

Execution time in pyspark - 3 min

Execution time in Scala spark - 12 min

Comment: how are you calculating execution time pyspark vs scala program? Is it just the query execution time?

Comment: Yes Amit , Its query execution time

Comment: Ok. and can you provide details of testing exec environment? number of cores etc.

Comment: I am executing it on a cluster having 3 nodes with 8 vCPU and 15 GiB

Comment: It's impossible. PySpark uses bridge to invoke Java and Scala code

Comment: What code? Query is only a part of application, in the meantime you can cache DataFrame, do some data manipulation. At least you should provide execution plans

Comment: @T.Gawęda Please find Scala and python code                                             https://github.com/navinkr/stackoverflow/wiki/ScalaSpark                                      https://github.com/navinkr/stackoverflow/wiki/PySpark

Comment: In Scala you are printing rows, in Python not - that's why Python is faster :)

Comment: @T.Gawęda Printing of rows are applicable to both Scala and python . Execution time was calculated just after execution of  final_trigrams  in both python and in Scala .